# How can we use string variable from another class in SQL statement

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, oracle11g

Login class:

```
public static String n=request.getParameter("userName");
```

public static  String p=request.getParameter("userPass");

Servlet class:

```
PreparedStatement ps1= con.prepareStatement("insert into "+Login.n+" values(?,?,?)");
```

In login class im using a html page where it shows name and password..so when ever user login it validates his pass by Loginps class and returns to login servlet where i placed html form are dress ,dou,pattern fileds ..here action given to servlet class where servlet class request parameters dress ,dou, pattern ...in preparedstatement("sql query have to insert into"+here i want string n value +"values (?,?,?)")

I want to use string `n` from `Login` class so that I can make a dynamic tables when user created his account.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: what is your problem now ? Any error?

Comment: When I'm trying to insert parameters from front end it's showing invalid table name...

Comment: it means your table name wrong . did you print the `Login.n` in console?

Comment: Yes I did it's taking that value as null...my question is how can I use variable of another class ...so that I can make dymanic tables for client when ever he signup

Comment: Can you share that other class? I can't say exactly with your current information.

Comment: i tried to share the code but it doesn't taking complete code..

Comment: Chat with them :https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81492/tamil-ios-android-and-web-developers

Comment: In login class im using a html page where it shows name and password..so when ever user login it validates his pass by Loginps class and returns to login servlet where i placed html form are dress ,dou,pattern fileds ..here action given to servlet class where servlet class request parameters dress ,dou, pattern ...in preparedstatement("sql query have to insert into"+here i want string n value +"values (?,?,?)")

Answer (score 0):

Login class:

```
String n=request.getParameter("userName");
String p=request.getParameter("userPass");

if("YOURSERVLETCLASS".checkUser(n, p))
{
    // anything you like for example forwarding to welcome page
    RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.html");
    rs.forward(request, response);
}else {
       // if not correct back to index page
       out.println("Username or Password incorrect");
       RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
       rs.include(request, response);
    }
```

Servlet class:

```
public static boolean checkUser(String n,String p){  
   boolean status=false;  
   try{  

   // set your connection here Connection con = .....

   PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(  
   "INSERT INTO userdetails(username,password)"+"VALUES(?,?)");  
   ps.setString(1,n);  
   ps.setString(2,p);  

   ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
   status=rs.next();  

   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}  
   return status;  
}
```

Comment: This will not answer to OP question